# How to select id in the div that was set by html()

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('#somediv').html(' <div id="innerDiv"> Testing </div>');
```

From the above statement I am setting the html for #somediv as

```
<div id="innerDiv"> Testing </div>
```

I want now to select innnerDiv. How do I do it??

eg:  $('#innnerDiv').html("Modified");

Comment: Your example seems like the correct solution to me. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by select?

Comment: are you trying to modify it before it was changed originally in your script?

Answer (score 1):

Just the way you did it, once the html is on the DOM you can select it

```
$('#innnerDiv')
```

if you want the html inside, you can use:

```
var htmlStr = $('#innnerDiv').html();
// in your case it will contain: Testing
```

Comment: Or just use `$("#innerDiv").text("Modified")` if you only changing the text

Answer (score 0):

what ever you have stated $('#innnerDiv').html("Modified"); is the correct way to access the #innerdiv and modify its content